# PHPMailer AddAddress()

Tags: php, formatting, phpmailer

I don't know how the data should be formatted for AddAddress PHPMailer function; I need the email to be sent to multiple recipients so I tried

```
$to = "me@example.com,you@example.net,she@example.it";
$obj->AddAddress($to);
```

but with no success.

Comment: PHPMailer can now (May 2015) handle this kind of address string via a parsing function. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30377848/333340)

Answer (score 81, accepted):

You need to call the `AddAddress` function once for each E-Mail address you want to send to. There are only two arguments for this function: `recipient_email_address` and `recipient_name`. The recipient name is optional and will not be used if not present.

```
$mailer->AddAddress('recipient1@example.com', 'First Name');
$mailer->AddAddress('recipient2@example.com', 'Second Name');
$mailer->AddAddress('recipient3@example.com', 'Third Name');
```

You could use an array to store the recipients and then use a `for` loop.

Comment: Though after the first `AddAddress()` it would make more sense to add the others with `AddCC()`.

Comment: No, that's not the same.

Comment: I think the new version of it is $mailer->addAddress('recipient1@domain.com', 'Name');

Comment: what does "recipient_name" exactly do? What exactly is the point of adding the name?

Answer (score 14):

You need to call the `AddAddress` method once for every recipient. Like so:

```
$mail->AddAddress('person1@example.com', 'Person One');
$mail->AddAddress('person2@example.com', 'Person Two');
// ..
```

To make things easy, you should loop through an array to do this.

```
$recipients = array(
   'person1@example.com' => 'Person One',
   'person2@example.com' => 'Person Two',
   // ..
);
foreach($recipients as $email => $name)
{
   $mail->AddAddress($email, $name);
}
```

Better yet, add them as Carbon Copy recipients.

```
$mail->AddCC('person1@example.com', 'Person One');
$mail->AddCC('person2@example.com', 'Person Two');
// ..
```

To make things easy, you should loop through an array to do this.

```
$recipients = array(
   'person1@example.com' => 'Person One',
   'person2@example.com' => 'Person Two',
   // ..
);
foreach($recipients as $email => $name)
{
   $mail->AddCC($email, $name);
}
```

Comment: Have to say, your easy versions look unnecessarily longer.

Comment: This is a copy of Alan Orozco's answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3149452/php-mailer-multiple-address

Comment: @redburn Yes and we can't give link as an answer, so thought of adding here.

Answer (score 6):

Some great answers above, using that info here is what I did today to solve the same issue:

```
$to_array = explode(',', $to);
foreach($to_array as $address)
{
    $mail->addAddress($address, 'Web Enquiry');
}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
foreach ($all_address as $aa) {
    $mail->AddAddress($aa); 
}
```

Comment: assuming that $all_address is array

Answer (score 0):

All answers are great. Here is an example use case for multiple add address:
The ability to add as many email you want on demand with a web form:

[See it in action with jsfiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/ozkantarik/kzp09vuk/)
(except the php processor)

```
### Send unlimited email with a web form
# Form for continuously adding e-mails:
<button type="button" onclick="emailNext();">Click to Add Another Email.</button>
<div id="addEmail"></div>
<button type="submit">Send All Emails</button>
# Script function:
<script>
function emailNext() {
    var nextEmail, inside_where;
    nextEmail = document.createElement('input');
    nextEmail.type = 'text';
    nextEmail.name = 'emails[]';
    nextEmail.className = 'class_for_styling';
    nextEmail.style.display = 'block';
    nextEmail.placeholder  = 'Enter E-mail Here';
    inside_where = document.getElementById('addEmail');
    inside_where.appendChild(nextEmail);
    return false;
}
</script>
# PHP Data Processor:
<?php
// ...
// Add the rest of your $mailer here...
if ($_POST[emails]){
    foreach ($_POST[emails] AS $postEmail){
        if ($postEmail){$mailer->AddAddress($postEmail);}
    }
} 
?>
```

So what it does basically is to generate a new input text box on every click with the name "emails[]".

The [] added at the end makes it an array when posted.

Then we go through each element of the array with "foreach" on PHP side adding the:

```
    $mailer->AddAddress($postEmail);
```