# PHP mail send to Multiple recipients

Tags: php, email

I have some PHP code that I'm using to send email to a specific e-mail address. However, I'd like to include a couple more e-mail addresses in the PHP for when it sends it.
when i tried it showing the following

**ERROR:Mailer Error: You must provide at least one recipient email address.**

**code**

```
include "class.phpmailer.php"; // include the class file name
$mail = new PHPMailer(); // create a new object
$mail->IsSMTP(); // enable SMTP
$mail->SMTPDebug = 1; // debugging: 1 = errors and messages, 2 = messages only
$mail->SMTPAuth = true; // authentication enabled
//$mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl'; // secure transfer enabled REQUIRED for GMail
$mail->Host = "mail.authsmtp.com";
$mail->Port = "25"; // or 587
$mail->IsHTML(true);
$mail->Username = "xxxxx";
$mail->Password = "xxxxx";
$mail->SetFrom("cpn@xxxxxxx.com");
$mail->Subject = $sub1;
$mail->Body = $text_mail;
$mail->AddAddress("xxxxxxx@gmail.com;aral@xxxxxx.com;akhader@xxxxxx.com");
 if(!$mail->Send()){
 echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
}
else{
 echo "Message has been sent";
}
```

any one guide me how to do it

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP mailer multiple address](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3149452/php-mailer-multiple-address)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Change this line

```
$mail->AddAddress("xxxxxxx@gmail.com;aral@xxxxxx.com;akhader@xxxxxx.com");
```

to this:

```
$mail->AddAddress("xxxxxxx@gmail.com");
$mail->AddAddress("aral@xxxxxx.com");
$mail->AddAddress("akhader@xxxxxx.com");
```

You can run that function as many times as you like until you've got all the addresses you need.

[See Here for more info](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3149528/1400370)

Answer (score 2):

It seems that you are miss using the `AddAdress` method. You should pass every mail separatly like that :

```
$mail->AddAddress("xxxxxxx@gmail.com");
$mail->AddAddress("aral@xxxxxx.com");
$mail->AddAddress("akhader@xxxxxx.com");
```

See [PHPMailer AddAddress()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1770765/phpmailer-addaddress) for more details.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to send email to multiple address,  You need to call the `AddAddress()` function for  each and every Email address. First parameter is `EMAIL address`, Second one is `Recipient` name and it is optional.

```
$mail->AddAddress("xxxxxxx@gmail.com", "XXXXXXXX");
$mail->AddAddress("aral@xxxxxx.com", "Aral");
```

Comment: @Bleeding Fingers, Thanks to pinting out!

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$mail->AddAddress("xxxxxxx@gmail.com");
$mail->AddAddress("aral@xxxxxx.com");
$mail->AddAddress("akhader@xxxxxx.com");
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look here [PHPMailer AddAddress()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1770765/phpmailer-addaddress)

and keep an eye of your line:

```
  $mail->AddAddress("xxxxxxx@gmail.com;aral@xxxxxx.com;akhader@xxxxxx.com");
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
$mail->AddAddress("xxxxxxx@gmail.com;aral@xxxxxx.com;akhader@xxxxxx.com");
```

You should use

```
$mail->AddAddress('xxxxxxx@gmail.com', '1');
$mail->AddAddress('aral@xxxxxx.com', '2');
$mail->AddAddress('akhader@xxxxxx.com', '3');
```

Or use CC copies:

```
$mail->AddCC('xxxxxxx@gmail.com', '1');
$mail->AddCC('aral@xxxxxx.com', '2');
$mail->AddCC('akhader@xxxxxx.com', '3');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.... This may help you

```
<html>
<body>

  <?php
  if (isset($_REQUEST['email']))
 //if "email" is filled out, send email
 {
 //send email
 $email = $_REQUEST['email'] ;
 $subject = $_REQUEST['subject'] ;
 $message = $_REQUEST['message'] ;
      mail("chauhanamrish32@gmail.com,amrinderpuri1990@gmail.com,amrinder_puri@yahoo.com,amrindersinghpuri13@gmail.com", $subject,$message, "From:" . $email);
  echo "Thank you for using our mail form";
  }
  else
//if "email" is not filled out, display the form
{
echo "<form method='post' action='mail.php'>
Email: <input name='email' type='text'><br>
Subject: <input name='subject' type='text'><br>
Message:<br>
<textarea name='message' rows='15' cols='40'>
</textarea><br>
<input type='submit'>
 </form>";
  }
?>
```