# how do i make this form (sleek contact form) send to multiple recipients?

Tags: forms, contacts, email-address

I'm looking to make a contact form send to more than 1 address. currently the code is

```
$to = 'email@email.com';
```

Further down the code is

```
function xmail($to,$subject,$message,$headers){
    global $usesmtp,$smtphost,$smtpport,$smtpuser,$smtppass,$smtpsecure,$_POST;
    if($usesmtp!=1){
        if(@mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers)){
            return 1;
        }
    }else{
        require_once('mail/class.phpmailer.php');
        $mail             = new PHPMailer();
        $body             =$message;
        $mail->IsSMTP();
        $mail->SMTPDebug  = 0; 
        $mail->SMTPAuth   = true;   
        $mail->SMTPSecure = $smtpsecure;       
        $mail->Host       = $smtphost;     
        $mail->Port       = $smtpport;                
        $mail->Username   = $smtpuser;  
        $mail->Password   = $smtppass;          
        $mail->SetFrom($_POST['email'], $_POST['name']);
        $mail->Subject    = $subject;
        $mail->AltBody    = "To view the message, please use an HTML compatible email viewer!"; 
        $mail->MsgHTML($body);
        $address        = $to;
        $mail->AddAddress($address, "Administrator");
        if($mail->Send()) {
          return 1;
        }
    }
}
```

Can anyone help please?

Comment: look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1770765/phpmailer-addaddress

Comment: try mailchimp.com for sending bulk emails

Comment: in fact, can't believe it was so easy as to make it $to = 'email@email.com, email2@email2.com';

Comment: Sorry, have done so now.

Answer (score 0):

Changed

```
$to = 'email@email.com';
```

To

```
$to = 'email@email.com, email2@email2.com';
```